# .NET 6 does not support .NET Standard 2.1?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-6.0

I just updated a project from .NET 5 to .NET 6. It compiles and runs perfectly locally. When I push this to azure, running my CI pipeline, an error is reporting that:

> NU1202: Package MyStandardPackaged 1.0 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package MyStandardPackaged 1.0 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Is there a workaround this, or I have to update this package declaring .NET 6?

Comment: [netstandard2.1 platform support](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.1.md#platform-support) states that .NET 5+ should support it.

Comment: I would be genuinely surprised by this, and I'm skeptical - wondering if this is more likely to be a problem with the build tools on your CI server. However! It should be perfectly *possible* (and arguably: desirable) to add a net 6 TFM. Again, I'm not saying that it is (or isn't) necessary, but; it seems incredibly unlikely.

Comment: I got this error when I accidentally launched my project with an older version of Visual Studio.  When I closed and re-opened it in VS 2022, these errors went away.  (Not the same scenario as the OP, but could help someone else.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you look very carefully at the error message you posted:

> NU1202: Package MyStandardPackaged 1.0 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package MyStandardPackaged 1.0 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Notice that it says that `net6.0` is `.NETFramework,Version=v6.0`. However, .NET 6 is actually `.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0`.

Therefore, I conclude you are using some old version of NuGet, that doesn't even know about .NET 5, to restore your project/solution.

My recommendation is to avoid the `NuGetCommand` task in Azure DevOps. Off the top of my head I can't think of any reason to use it, all the important features needed for a CI script exists in the `dotnet` CLI and `MSBuild.exe`.

Therefore, if all the projects in your solution/repo are SDK style (contain `Sdk="whatever"` in the project file), then use `dotnet restore`. If you have even a single non-SDK style project (every `.cs` in the directory is listed in the XML) then use `msbuild -t:restore`.  This way, you'll never have a problem of mismatched NuGet versions again.

Comment: I actually am using the `NuGetCommand` and after I republished my project adding .Net 6 explicitly it all worked...

Comment: That will be because the old version of NuGet will incorrectly think both the package and project are using .NET Framework version 6.0, which doesn't actually exist. It also means you don't have performance improvements or bug fixes, or features like package source mapping available to you.  I still strongly recommend you stop using `NuGetCommand` and instead directly invoke `dotnet restore` or `msbuild -t:restore` from a command line task instead.

Comment: In fact, that's also the suggestion from the Azure DevOps team themselves: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11406#issuecomment-982099267 https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15542#issuecomment-982091805

Comment: I noticed that the message talks about net60 without the period, while the correct TFM is net6.0. Maybe there was an issue with that...