# Building ASPNetCore 6.0 project: Microsoft packages not compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v6.0, but support .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0 instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jenkins, build, .net-6.0

I've built an ASPNetCore 6.0 website using Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.4), everything works fine on my development machine.

I'm now trying to deploy it via a Jenkins build server. I first installed the .Net 6.0.2 SDK and ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.2 Hosting bundle via https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0. Did a reboot as requested after the Hosting Bundle.

I'm now running command `dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release .\path\to\my.csproj /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile` and I'm getting a bunch of errors such as this one:

`error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)`

and

`error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)`

Also with the same error are packages Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.2,  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.2

I don't understand why it is telling me that it seems to have downloaded packages that support .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0 but wants packages that are compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v6.0. I thought the whole point with .NET 6.0 is that there is no longer any differentiation between Core and Framework, it's all the same thing?

To ensure I'm running the correct version of the tooling (checking the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251470/206852), `dotnet --version` gives `6.0.200`. When running `dotnet publish` the first thing it says is `Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET`.

All projects in the solution are SDK style (in that in the .csproj file they contain `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` or `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, and all target net6.0 `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

EDIT: I noticed that a few packages are giving a slightly different error, here's the entire list of errors (I've removed the project path which is originally included at the start of each line):

`error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0).Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.2 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)`

In the errors in the last half of this list "win7-x86" is referenced. I have no idea why, this is a Windows Server 2012 server running on a 64-bit OS, I have installed the 64-bit version of the SDK (verified looking in Programs and Features).

Comment: What is the target framework in the `*.csproj` file? the difference in the version mentioned in the `*.csproj` file and the installed .net core run time could lead to the said error. I would suggest trying to install the same exact version of the .net core run time and try to publish the site. See whether it helps to fix the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT the target framework is net6.0 in all projects in the solution. Are you saying to install the 6.0.0 SDK instead of 6.0.2?

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes, you could try to install the .NetCore runtime 6.0 or keep the same version of the *.csproj file and .NetCore runtime.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I uninstalled the 6.0.2 SDK and everything associated with .Net6 in Programs and Features, I then installed the .Net 6.0.100 SDK (6.0.0 not available), I verified the version with `dotnet --version` which returns 6.0.100, I then tried dotnet publish again, same errors as before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after a lot of headache, I finally solved this. I did many things, so I'm not sure what was actually necessary and what was not, but I'll detail the steps here.

Firstly, I had 3 .NET core SDKs installed on the server including 6.0.200. I uninstalled all of them and rebooted. I then installed 6.0.200 again and rebooted.

I tried to rebuild again at this point and got a different error: `MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found` - this was weird because the SDK was definitely installed and in the right place etc etc.

This led me to https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10229 and https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2532 which led me to create a new environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath` pointing at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\Sdks`, it took another reboot get Jenkins to pick this up, but after that, the build started working :)