# GUI code for .Net 6 using .Net MAUI fails to compile

Tags: .net, user-interface, maui

I started out using command line dotnet to create a .Net 6 C# project. Now I would like to add a GUI to this (GUI3). As I understand it .Net MAUI should be possible for this ?
However after using Visual Studio to add such a project , I am told that I cannot reference this project from my original project. The output says

: error NU1201: Project GUI3 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Project GUI3 supports:
error NU1201:   - net6.0-maccatalyst16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
error NU1201:   - net6.0-windows10.0.22621 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Now I have two questions:

- Are there two versions of .Net 6 ? I thought it was only one, that the difference between .Net Core and .Net Windows were eliminated in .Net 6
- What GUI can I use if I cannot use MAUI

Comment: Was there text after `Project GUI3 supports:`, but before the next `error NU1201`?

Comment: Where is the code? Where's the project file? Please shoe all relevant code and configurations.

Comment: `supports: net6.0 .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)` looks to be how Microsoft refers to `.net6.0`, in certain messages. `-windows10.0.22621` identifies the *platform* being targetted. https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/net5/net5.md, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/targetframework-name-change, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71374503/building-aspnetcore-6-0-project-microsoft-packages-not-compatible-with-netfram.

Comment: But to answer your underlying question: don't try to add Maui as an afterthought. (Don't try to reference a Maui project from your non-Maui c# project.) FIRST create a Maui project, using the Maui template. THEN move your existing c# source files into that project. That's the easiest way to work. IF you really want to keep that c# separate, use `class library` template. NOT a standalone executable, which is what your original project is.

Comment: the relevant code is only "var g = new GUI3(), so I try to initiate the GUI. I tried to MAUI Class Library, but that does not include any Graphics at all, so not sure where to start. It is a workaround, but so far I think the most promising is to start out by creating a MAUI app, and then put my console code in there. I am not 100% happy with it, because I feel I loose control over the code, maybe I should revisit the library option later, I guess that is what I need to do to feel I control the code, and not opposite.